# Single word(s) to express that something starts counting at 0 or 1?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the context of computers there are containers, e.g. arrays that assign indexes to their elements beginning with 0 for the first element 1 for the second element, 2 for the third element, etc.

There are also containers that start counting with 1 for the first element and 2 for the second element.

Is there a single word that denotes this property?

Example:

> The coordinate array is ___ , you can access the first element with the index 0. The polygon set is ____, the first element has the index 1.

Comment: [But ask the Wee Pedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) and ye shall receive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words you are looking for are **zero-based** and **one-based**:

> **Zero-based numbering** or *index origin = 0* is a way of numbering in which the initial element of a sequence is assigned the index 0, rather than the index 1 as is typical in everyday *non-mathematical/non-programming* circumstances.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia: Zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)</sub>

> **1-based indexing**
>   Definition: Indexing (an array) beginning with 1.
>   <sub>Paul E. Black, "1-based indexing", in [Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/oneBasedIndexing.html)</sub>

For example:

- [Why are zero-based arrays the norm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/110804)
- [The History of Python: Why Python uses 0-based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html)
- [List of 1-indexed programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1499749/6083675)

I've also heard of [**zero-indexed**](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14993426) being used, but I guess it's less common.

Comment: The main use of *zero-indexed* (IMO) is to avoid using the same word as in *base 2*, *base 10* etc.